# How to specify "," as 3-character delimiter string in .csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to specify (when reading a file) and assign (in output) this 3-character string`","` as `.csv` delimiter? For example: `"col1","col2","col3","col4"`

The code where it needs to be used for reading and output:

```
import csv
with open('a.csv', 'r') as infile, open('reordered.csv', 'a') as outfile:
    fieldnames = ['B', 'C', 'A', 'D']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

I tried to look it up (https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), etc. but it is not clear.

UPDATE: As pointed out by others, this may not be `","` delimiter, but a `,` delimiter and `"values"`. Regardless, my values contain commas `,`, so the `","` pattern between columns helps to maintain column structure.

Comment: Have you tried using something like `delimiter='","'`?

Comment: if not try ''' "," ''' (3x ')

Comment: `quotechar='"'` and `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`

Comment: I don't think you want the quotes to be part of the delimiter, since this would result in the column values being `"col1`, `col2`, `col3` and `col4"`

Comment: Yes, I tried: Error: `"delimiter" must be a 1-character string`.

Comment: What Peter Wood said. Tell the CSV reader & writer that you are using quoted fields, and to use a single comma as the delimiter.

Comment: @vonludi: I see your logic, so I probably should say, delimiter is a single comma `,` and values are in `"value"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to define the [quote character](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar), setting the delimiter will not get you the desired results.

```
import csv
with open('a.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Edit: As for changes to your code, it would look somewhat like this:

```
with open('a.csv', 'r') as infile, open('reordered.csv', 'a') as outfile:
    fieldnamesout = ['B', 'C', 'A', 'D']
    fieldnamesin = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', fieldnames=fieldnamesin)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', fieldnames=fieldnamesout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Note the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`, which instructs the writer to quote all fields according to the `quotechar`, this may or may not be what you want, other options would be `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`.

Comment: Thank you. I do see your logic, but I am having trouble inserting into my code above (column rearrange). Could you pls give some help as to what part of my code needs to be replaced?

Comment: Very nice, `","` preserved in rearranged columns.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your values are string literals. I don't know if the cvs module can handle this out of the box. It is not a parsing problem it is a data processing problem.

Your values are in the quote chars. So either you truncate them when processing your data `field_value.replace('"', '')` and add them back later on `'"{}"'.format(field_value)` or you straight operate on the data fields leaving the quote char in place.